# Method declaration in superclass

Tags: java, declaration, superclass

I wan't to make a method declaration in a superclass called 'dataItem' so that all subclasses that implement that method must have a return type that is of that implementing class. Is that possible?

For example if I have class 'Experiment' which implements 'dataItem' and I have method newItem() . Which for 'Experiment' should only be able to return 'Experiment' datatype and not any other implementation of 'dataItem'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force a class method to return the type it is a member of. You have to actually specify it.

```
public class DataItem {
    public DataItem getItem() {return null;}
}

public class Experiment extends DataItem {
    @Override
    public Experiment getItem() {return null;}
}
```

This works because `Experiment` is a sub class of `DataItem` and can therefore be used anywhere a `DataItem` could be used.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're looking for this:

```
public interface dataitem<T>
{
    public T newItem();
};

public class Element implements dataitem<Element>
{
    @Override
    public Element newItem()
    {
        return new Element();
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it is a possible solution. I'm just wondering why someone would do that. @numfar, could you explain us the reason why you want this?

Comment: @Trein it is useful for iterators for example, so you can define interface with abstract type T, and then all subclasses MUST implement proper functions